# What are the differences of the various kinds of black print color?

Tags: color, black

Some terms for black color I have seen are:

- Process Black
- Pantone Black C
- rich black

Do others exist?
What makes them different?

Comment: Related, perhaps duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/what-kind-of-black-should-i-use-when-designing-for-cmyk-print

Answer (score 1):

Process black and Rich black are both similar if not the same. The black is created with a mixture of Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, and Black. In 4 color printing it makes sure the back is saturated.

Pantone black is a spot color or a specific ink.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_black

Comment: Isn't process black 100% black (vs rich black, which is typically 100% black along with percentages of the other process colors)