# Preparing screenshots for use in a print document

Tags: print-design, software-recommendation, screenshot

I would like to feature screenshots of websites taken on my phone, tablet and laptop in a print document.

The print document is 300 ppi and the screenshots are 72 ppi.
Importing the screenshots directly into the printed document obviously gives poor quality images.

How do I prepare the screenshots for print use and get a professional finish?

Comment: I understand that there is a similar question at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7560/optimizing-a-screenshot-for-adding-in-a-document-and-printing however, that question has focused on discussing DPI and PPI rather than the production of print quality images from a screenshot which is what the question is about. There are better quality responses attached to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is dimension of the print document ? If its very big with compare to the screenshots, If 1 px of screenshots is same as 1 px of print document , then you can leave it as it is. That is if you don't have to scale the screenshots, it is fine for printing, and you ignore PPI.

---

**Some things to follow.**

- Adjust colors of screenshots, CMYK mode will be best.
- Adjust curve,levels etc.
- Don't scale image up/down
- [**Use this**](http://screenshot.wutils.com/) to get screenshots with bigger dimensions.

---

Don't consider PPI/DPI as quality of an image, as long as screenshot-size remain same as final print size, its just fine.

Comment: The dimension of the print document could be anything. An example could be wanting to use a screenshot of a phone app in a magazine. A common magazine size is 21.27cm x 27.62cm.

Comment: The site you mentioned (http://screenshot.wutils.com) did the job perfectly. I tried it on the BBC website and was able to generate a 4400x6600 pixel screenshot.
It's available to view online at http://screenshot.wutils.com/thumb/http_www_bbc_co_uk_4400x6600z200.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/30858/take-a-high-resolution-screenshot-of-a-website) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841536/take-a-high-resolution-screenshot-from-a-web-page), but I think having it here too is okay. Its something I never even considered.

The answer appears to be to use [Phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/) or one of the websites people have already built with it:

- [Screenshot Utilities from the Phantom.js website](http://phantomjs.org/related-projects.html)
- [Screenshot utility someone on StackOverflow made using Phantom.js](http://screenshot.wutils.com/)

I haven't used any Phantom methods before, but might have to remember this.

Another option, which I have personally used, is magnifying the page (<kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> and taking screenshot(s) that way, then combining them into one large image as necessary.

In the magnifying of page you'll have to be weary of raster images, they will get pixelated which might defeat the purpose. I'm not sure how it works with the services, I imagine the same since I don't know how it would convert raster into a vector format. I'll test this when I get to my office and edit to confirm.