# How do I keep high resolution pics when posting screenshots to a piece of paper to keep it from getting blurry when printed?

Tags: print-design, photo-editing, resolution, adobe-acrobat, screenshot

I am making a cheat sheet with a bunch of equations and notes on them. I essentially take screenshots of the notes on my computer, and then paste them to a word document, and then resize them to make them smaller so I can fit more. I can visibly see the notes on my word document (even when at same size and zoom as a standard piece of paper), but when I print it out everything becomes blurry.

What's a good way to remedy this situation? I tried saving as PDF, then printing as an image because supposedly that would be higher quality but this doesn't work. Is this because of the printer or the resolution of the photo itself? I suspect it may be the printer is not able to print in such high resolution as well. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimizing a screenshot for adding in a document and printing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7560/optimizing-a-screenshot-for-adding-in-a-document-and-printing)

Comment: @Danielillo Nope. I checked it out and not the same. Thanks though

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What kind of printer are you using? Is it laser, inkjet, professional digital printing, professional lithographic printing, or something else? What is the maximum resolution of the printer? Can you show us one of the screen captures? Can you show a photograph of the resulting print that shows the problem? Can you share the PDF?  It might not be possible to answer this question properly without more information. Please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/122128/edit) to add the missing information. Thanks.

Comment: Try scaling the image up with reatest neghbour to disable the interpolation of printer

Answer (score 1):

Your issue most likely is that the scaling of the raster graphic is happening in Word, which doesn't have a good graphics engine at all.

Inkscape, Illustrator, Affinity Designer, InDesign - ANY layout or vector graphics package will handle this well - heck even Microsoft Publisher will handle this better than Word.

As correctly pointed out by @Billy Kerr, it can also be a low-quality printer with too large a half-tone screen dot size to allow for super-fine text to even *be* printed.

Comment: This could also be a printer problem. For example, if it's a monochrome home/ofice laser printer, the half-tone dots could potentially be too big for tiny text.