# What should be considered when using very thin lines on a print piece?

Tags: print-design, print-production

I'm designing a card game and my friend (who is a graphic designer and works at a commercial printing establishment) told me to keep in mind the thinness of my lines when sending the docs to print.

An example of one of the graphics she was concerned about (the front box art):
[image] (sized at 3.5" x 4" when printed)

The background of the lines are at a .5pt stroke thickness in Illustrator and print fine when I print from a digital printer. I've never had any experience with offset printing yet. Would my graphic be too difficult to get good results? Should I find a different solution for the background?

Comment: FWIW, it's a nice card, but aesthetically, I'd beef up the lines on your banner/text at the bottom just to be in balance with everything else.

Comment: It's a guild of thieves, right? Then it's **THIEVES' GUILD**. With the apostrophe. </proofreader>

Comment: @LaurenIpsum You're right, but I think I've seen it written without an apostrophe before in some RPG/fantasy.

Comment: **Remark:** In classical typography, `0.4pt` is the standard for "thin lines". However, for example the [AMS submission guide at page 9](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amscls/instr-l.pdf) suggest not to use lines thinner than `0.5pt`.

Comment: @tohecz And it would tick me off there too. :) Just because other people do it incorrectly doesn't make it correct by consensus.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I'm not native, but in Czech, we would likely omit an apostrophe in a display title like this. Tha's probably the reason why I've never seen it: because it was always written as a sign, and not in text. (However, this is an off-topic comment spam, so I think we should stop it.)

Comment: @tohecz So you're saying you don't spellczech?

Comment: I can go both ways: a group *can* be said to be a possession of the member items, but it is not a requirement. "Integers Set" etc.

Comment: Should I migrate this to English.se? lol

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two considerations I'm aware of:

### Misregistration

Assuming this is based on overlaid inks (e.g. CMYK) not premixed inks (e.g. Pantone spot colours), it's not a bad idea to try to **minimise the number of inks** used in the colours in thin or high detail areas such as thin lines and fine text.

This is because for fine lines, tiny registration errors (different colour ink plates or layers being mis-aligned to each other by very small amounts) become noticeable, making a line that should be sharp look blurry or, in extreme cases, giving the appearance of separate adjacent cyan, magenta, yellow and/or black lines.

Here's an example of misregistration [borrowed from a CreateSpace thread](https://www.createspace.com/en/community/thread/21504). What should be thin black lines in this type are slightly blurry with an unintended yellowy glow, from the yellow and magenta inks being printed slightly too far down and left.

[image]

So, for this pictured design, I'd normally set the diagnonal lines' strokes (and also the "A GAME BY DAVID SCOTT" thin text) to pure K "plain" black (0C,0M,0Y,100K), while keeping the solid blacks (border, shield, etc) as [rich black](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10901/).

Normally, you'd never allow two mixes of black to touch each other like how the 100%K diagonals touch the rich black border, because it would create a false edge between the two blacks - but in this case there's already an edge where the border stops.

If it was a design based on a different colour, I might try to find a variant of that colour for the thin details that was a close match but used the minimum number of different inks. 
This is usually more important for text (preserving readability) than for decorative lines though.

---

### DPI / [LPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lines_per_inch) of the print setup

Not to be confused with the PPI of a digital file - this is about the capabilities of the print setup (including paper type). This is probably not an issue unless you're printing super-thin lines below 0.25pt, or printing to a low DPI/LPI setup, e.g. poor quality paper (e.g. newsprint) or large format (e.g. billboard).

Most printing involves your (presumably vector) image being converted into an arrangement of dots of C,M,Y,K ink. The print set up will have a maximum number of dots it can print per inch. If your line is thinner than one of the printer's dots, it's going to struggle to get close to looking like a perfectly crisp and straight line.

If the print specs mean this is likely to be an issue, find out the details from the printer and adjust the "0.25pt minimum" rule of thumb accordingly. For a box for a card game, however, this would almost certainly not be a problem for a 0.5pt line (unless it's a really ropey printer place).

Comment: Note that for the art supplied (excepting the grey shading on the authorship ribbon), it *could* be printed one color without screening in which case the LPI is not relevant.

Answer (score 11):

In most cases, a **minimum line weight for commercial printing is .25pt**. Anything that weight or larger should hold up just fine.

Keep the .25pt in mind if you reduce an image.

Comment: and it should be noted that would be for solid lines. If we're talking colored lines, via CMYK printing, that may be too narrow for the printer to properly register.

Comment: I started to add that in fact. Then realized I've had many pieces printed with built color .25pt lines and not had issue with those. I think that may depend upon the pressman and print provider. For online print vendors, I'd probably stick to a .5pt minimum.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it's doable, but depends entirely on the particular printer. I've dealt with good ones and, well, 'affordable' ones. ;)

Comment: And a printing shop can ensure a minimum line thickness (i.e. thicken lines that are so thin they become invisible).

Comment: @Scott do you have references for that number or is it based on your experience with commercial printers? I always assumed 300 dpi was the industry standard printing resolution. So 0.25pt should be about 1 dot across (72/300) * 0.25 is approximately 1. Is that a safe limit?

Comment: @JochemKuijpers 30+ years of experience. Most prepress software such as Preps will automatically convert thin lines to .25pt. In fact, it's even an option in Acrobat Pro.