# What will be the size in photoshop of 27x10 feet?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to make a banner which is having size od 27*10 so what will be the size in photoshop?

Comment: Or [Creating large banners to be viewed from a distance, at a size Illustrator can't handle](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64060/creating-large-banners-to-be-viewed-from-a-distance-at-a-size-illustrator-cant) or [I need to print an image a certain size. What dimensions and resolutions should I use?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolutions-should)

Answer (score 0):

[image]
You can change the unit of measure to inches, in your case, it is 27*12 inches x 10*12 inches. Then change the resolution to be same as the printing.

300 pixels/inch is usual for magazines, but this leads to a colossal need of storage if the image is this big. Ask the right resolution from the printhouse.

Answer (score 0):

If your are printing the flex or banner. Never calculate that in measurement in foot. If u mention the measurement in foot that is 27 feet x 12 feet the empty file will be in 9.7 GB what you will work in such a heavy file.[image]

Apply this formula to make a banner is make it in inches 
1 foot = 12 inch
That is 27/12 = 2.25 inch 
and 12/12 = 1 inch

so 2.25 inch x 1 inch with 500 dpi and CYMK
You can make much easier to excess.
[image]