# 150 meter Illustrator artwork

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize

My client needs a seamless pattern of 150 meter with each objects are at a size of 25 cm. I mean 25 cm flower in a 150 meter pattern. So approximately 600*600=360000 flowers.Illustrator is just running on fumes when I tried at 1:30 scale. Has anyone faced this kind of project before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating large banners to be viewed from a distance, at a size Illustrator can't handle](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64060/creating-large-banners-to-be-viewed-from-a-distance-at-a-size-illustrator-cant)

Comment: How are you getting 600 * 600? I’m guessing you mean it’s 150 flowers per 25 x 25 cm square, not 150 flowers per 25 cm (those would be _tiny_ flowers), but where does 600 * 600 come from? How tall is the whole piece even meant to be?

Comment: I wanted to say each flowers in the pattern should be 25 cm in size. So for a 15000 cm width and height this repeated pattern would cost me like 600*600 or 600² for filling this pattern by each row and each column. this is approximate estimate. Anyways it will be closer to that number.

Comment: The whole thing will be 150 x 150 m = 22,500 m2? That’s **enormous**, nearly the size of three football (soccer) pitches! You’ll definitely need a seamlessly repeating pattern and then print in tiles for that.

Comment: do we know if Dynamic Symbols (i.e. Instancing) performs better than a pattern fill? Is it handled the same way under the hood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a seamless pattern

So... Make a... (drums here) seamless pattern!

Make a pattern that repeats itself in a way you do not see the seams!

The size of **each module** depends on the printing method, context, viewing distances, subject, purpose, etc, etc. This is why they are hiring you in the first place, to solve this.

---

Some examples.

You have an apple pie and you want to make a pattern on the top with a [roller cutter](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=apple%20pie%20roller%20cutter&rlz=1C1GKLA_enMX664MX664&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU48TU4rvcAhUHQq0KHVIMA5IQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=1012). The pattern gets repeated each turn.

You print a wallpaper... an actual wallpaper for an actual wall. The pattern will repeat each roll, let's say 90 cm?

It can be 1 repetition or several. Depends on the roll, depends on the printing method.

Comment: I made a seamless pattern but its way too heavy for my rig I guess. So many objects in this thing.

Comment: @L.MOE If you have a seamless pattern, you only need one repetition. Send the printer the file with one square of seamless pattern, they print enough to fill the 150-meter rig, and the individual parts are attached to the rig.

Comment: Now I get it . So I can just make one piece with no space left so it can be repeated over and over again?

Comment: Depends on the " printing method, context, viewing distances, subject, purpose, etc, etc." You need to ask more details of the project.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a printer that can print 150m in one run, so find out what the print run size is and render one run at a time.

Also render one flower to print resolution and stitch together in raster not vector.