# How can I export an image from Illustrator image at multiple sizes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, ppi, pixel

I am new to Adobe Illustrator and I have a logo image which I need to use in 5 or 6 different sizes.  The logo image was created in Adobe Illustrator, but when I try to save the image to PNG or JPEG what should have been simple turns out to be very complicated.

I understand that Adobe Illustrator wants to treat the image as a certain size, and then wants to multiply that size by a pixels per inch scale factor to result in the actual number of pixels that it saves.  It has a few limited scale factor choices which give a *very* limited set of resulting output pixel sizes.

However for many web uses the user already knows the output pixel dimensions that are needed. Is there a way of just specifiying either the pixel width or height of the saved graphic which is needed?

I have seen suggestions to export the image and then use Photoshop to resize it, but that results in a poorer image quality vs. creating the final image from the vector image.

Comment: Related: [Best workflow to save an image in 3 different sizes](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/18322/8708)

Comment: theres number of ways to do that, mine is select all then image you want to export then theres the width and height option in the header, just change it then export it

Answer (score 29, accepted):

File > Save for Web and then enter the pixel dimensions by clicking the `Image Size` tab on the right of the Save for Web window.

Or am I not understanding you correctly?

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I've just spent around 15 minutes with the "export"-function, but since it refuses to use less than 72ppi, I had to rescale the artwork and artboard for very small exports, that's propably what the asker did as well.

Comment: Since this is the 'accepted' answer, let me bump it up almost a decade. Contemporary versions of AI (in 2021) will consider 'Save for Web' as _legacy_, offering an additional (new) export function. Here you can click the checkbox for 'Include Bleed' (assuming that your Artboard specifies the correct dimensions) and then select whatever size(s) and file format(s) you wish (JPEG, PNG, SVG, PDF). AI will batch-save them all in all sizes.

Answer (score 13):

Using `File → Save for Web` and entering the dimensions will do what you're after. Also, Illustrator uses vector scaling, so the results are better than if you tried the same thing in Photoshop — entering dimensions that don't match the document in Photoshop means the image will be bitmap scaled.

Please note that you have to click Apply after changing the dimensions, if you're using a version of Illustrator prior to CS6.

[image: Save for Web in Illustrator]

Oh, and there's a very good chance you'll want `Convert to sRGB` turned off — it destructively converts your image from the current colour space to sRGB, making colours shift.

[image]

Comment: There is no Apply button in CS6.... and I disagree about Convert to RGB, you want that **ON** for images destined for the web.

Comment: Thanks regarding the CS6 tip. Leaving Convert to sRGB on is *absolutely* the wrong approach for web and UI work. Here's an entire article on why: http://bjango.com/articles/photoshop/ (Contest me on this at your peril!)

Comment: Citing your own article as if it has any more credibility than your opinion here is a bit ludicrous. ANYONE can create a web page which supports ANY opinion, right or wrong. Heck I've seen entire in-depth web sites dedicated to explaining completely inappropriate color management techniques. 25+ years of practice means more to me. That along with direct discussions with people like Andrew Rodney, Bruce Fraser, and Chris Cox. Unless you can absolutely control the color profiles on EVERY monitor your work will be seen on, you want sRGB. We'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Did you actually read the article? When you're doing web and UI work, exact colour values MUST be maintained throughout the entire process. If you enter #FF0010 as a colour, that MUST be output in the file as #FF0010 if you intent to match the colour in code. This means Convert to sRGB MUST be off. I get the feeling you don't do this kind of work and don't understand what's involved.

Comment: Scott, please don't take this as an ad hominem attack, but from similar discussions I think you may have picked up some erroneous ideas about RGB colour representation. See also http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7815/rgb-and-cmyk-why-both/7816#comment11572_7816.

Comment: Those comments are irrelevant e100. You were being a bit captious about the numbers I used even though I stated many times I was merely generalizing. And of course, I did not read your article, Mark. Whether you all think it or not. I do actually know some things I post about. I'm not some 25 year old, fresh out of school designer. Again.. we'll have to agre to disagree. There's a REASON the Save for Web team implemented the Convert to sRGB option. It did not exist initially.

Comment: Yes to get FF0010 to match an image containing FF0100 you may experience better results **on your monitor** if your monitor is poorly calibrated, by turning off convert to sRGB. However, as I've posted, unless you can control the color calibration of every single monitor in the world which will see your work, then you **want** to convert to sRGB. That ensures poorly calibrated monitors or non-color managed browsers match the colors as well. It's easy if everything you do is for UIs and iDevices, since it's all color managed. Not so easy for web design.

Comment: In the end, I'm glad that what you all use works for you. So continue to use it. What I use works for me and has for decades. So, my opinion is not going to be altered. I trust my experience far more than anything. As I've posted, **we'll simply have to agree to disagree**.

Comment: Convert to sRGB is the wrong choice in almost every conceivable situation when working for web. "There's a REASON the Save for Web team implemented the Convert to sRGB option" — Time to get that fixed. http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/convert_to_srgb_should_be_off_by_default_or_removed_altogether

Answer (score 1):

When I need to support multiple pixel sizes I dupe and scale the art within the same AI file. Each size goes onto a separate correctly sized artboard. I append the board name with the file format to be exported. Then I run a jsx that exports each artboard and picks up the file format from the name, using the last settings I entered for that format in that file. This is all in CS5.

I use this workflow for some logos, icons, and display ads.

Comment: Please, can you share the .jsx?

Comment: @kelin I'm afraid I can't. It's been a long time since I've bothered with Adobe products.

Comment: Not a problem, I found great script here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28067227/3050403

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a document of the appropriate size in Photoshop (or box out an area with guides) then File > Place the vector art.

You can scale the size of the shape before it is rendered. Obviously scaling after that will reduce its quality.

I've always used this technique for logos in order to give precise control over size, eg getting the baseline of the logo's text elements on a pixel boundary (a form of hinting).

Answer (score 0):

An addition to this subject which I found intresting for mobile app designers, is [this script](http://www.hotappsfactory.com/the-magic-illustrator-script-ai-to-ios-android/) that creates retina assets for iOS and Android in 1 click.