# Color mode problems in illustrator CC 2017

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud

I m creating a artwork in CMYK mode and i want a jpg in RGB form but colors art different in output.
This problems is started from updating illustrator CC 2017.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell for sure without a picture, but what you're describing sounds like normal behavior, when converting CMYK to RGB.

The two color spaces are different from each other in several ways and the intended use of your design should be considered, when choosing your initial document settings.

I won't get into too much detail about the differences between the two here*, but know that they have slightly different gamuts (ranges of colors they can display).

See below for a visualization of the two:

[image]

As you can see, the CMYK and RGB gamuts overlap in many areas, but each color space has ranges of colors not available in the other.  This is where your conversion issues are likely coming from.

**Just remember:**

- If you are designing for screens, use RGB from the beginning
- If you are designing for print, then use CMYK

---

*There are *tons* of resources available online describing the differences between the two color spaces.  [This post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7815/rgb-and-cmyk-why-both) has some decent answers, to help you learn more about CMYK/RGB color spaces.

Comment: Aren't the color profiles what is in charge of conversion of color spaces? Maybe their color management is not in sync or being not used.

Comment: @Silly-V sort of but their main purpose is not to preserve color, as such. So for example a perceptual conversion intent does actually change colors but retain the relative difference between the colors.. Anyway CMYK being substantive us just a red herring, it has no bearing on the issue.

Comment: @joojaa When the questioner said the "output is different" I assumed they were talking about as in "different" from their previous output. All the while, taking into consideration the basic changes a document goes through when jumping color spaces. You see what I'm saying?

Comment: @Silly-V yes well most likely they never were calibrated in the first place.