# Why don't low-opacity colours blend the way I expect?

Tags: color, color-theory

As an experiment, I made three fill layers in Photoshop: one red (`#ff0000`), one green (`#00ff00`) and one blue (`#0000ff`). I set each layer to 33% opacity.

I thought they would blend together to make white (or something close), but they made a murky blue colour.

Can someone help me understand why?

Comment: ))) you need to learn a bit about additive and  substractive color models

Comment: This will be helpful: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60/what-is-the-difference-between-cmyk-and-rgb-are-there-other-color-spaces-i-shou

Comment: It depends a lot on what kind of "blending" exactly you did - you should add that to the question.

Comment: opacity isn't necessarily blending, but note that unless you are properly blending them at 100%, it will never be white (white is 100% R G & B). At 33% you'll end up with a dark gray.

Comment: @Vnovak yep that's why I asked a question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contrary to the comments above, [alpha blending](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) does not use a subtractive colour system. You can observe that it is not a subtractive scheme by overlaying lots of translucent layers - were it subtractive, it would turn black.

The usual way alpha blending works is in the "over" mode, which is like painting *over* the previous layers. This works essentially by taking an average of the colour of a layer and the blended colour of layer below. This kind of blending mimics painting with a semitransparent paint on top of another image. It's probably best to use your example:

We begin, for the sake of demonstration, with white

```
             Red     Green     Blue   Alpha
Background    1        1        1       1
```

and we add a red layer with 33% opacity

```
             Red     Green     Blue   Alpha
Background    1        1        1       1
 Red Layer    1        0        0      1/3
```

the red colour is then blended with the previous layer in a ratio of 1:2 (i.e. 33%)

```
                  Red     Green     Blue
Background Part   2/3      2/3       2/3
 Red Layer Part   1/3        0         0 
     Total         1       2/3       2/3
```

In this example, where the background has an alpha of 1, it stays at 1 no matter what.

This first layer is actually something like what you'd get if you physically mixed two paints. But when there is more than one overlay, **the order matters**, and it is not like mixing paints. This becomes apparent when we add the green layer

```
                   Red     Green     Blue   Alpha
       Background   1        1        1       1
      + Red Layer   1        0        0      1/3
= After Red Layer   1       2/3      2/3      1
    + Green Layer   0       1/3       0      1/3
```

We do the same, 2/3 of the layer below, and 1/3 of the new layer

```
                       Red     Green     Blue   
After-Red-Layer Part   2/3      4/9      4/9    
    Green Layer Part    0       1/3       0     
               Total   6/9      7/9      4/9
```

Already you can see that the alpha values you've used don't match the proportions of the resulting colours. It's slightly more green than red, even though the red and green layer have the same opacity. If the layers were in the other order, then it would be slightly more red than green.

So far we have

```
                     Red     Green     Blue   Alpha
         Background   1        1        1       1
        + Red Layer   1        0        0      1/3
  = After Red Layer   1       2/3      2/3      1
      + Green Layer   0       1/3       0      1/3
= After Green Layer  2/3      7/9      4/9      1
```

and the last calculation for the blue layer is

```
                         Red     Green     Blue   
After-Green Layer Part   4/9     14/27     8/27
       Blue Layer Part    0        0       1/3     
                 Total   4/9     14/27     17/27
------------------------------------------------
       Total times 27:   12        14      17
Total times 256 = RGB:  113        132     161  (hex:7184a1ff)
     (rounded down)
```

which is this colour:

[image]

The way the alpha changes is in the wikipedia article, and is a little more complicated. When the background has an alpha of 1 we don't need to worry about it.

(Mathematically, this scheme has a really nice property where the blended colour is determined by the layers colour and the blended colour made by the previous layers - you don't need to know the colours of all the individual layers below, just the colour these layers make. This is unlike what would happen in physical mixing of the colours, which is more difficult to calculate as the effect adding an extra colour layer requires knowing the colour and 'amounts' of every layer below)

Comment: Fantastic answer. I wouldn't have had the patience to list out all the arithmetic, but you've ended up with a wonderfully clear exposition of a pretty esoteric and broadly misunderstood subject.