# Why won't my RGB file print as RGB in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, color-spaces

In InDesign, I have a file that's RGB (and I set the 'intent' as web, so the program is reading it as an RGB document-I could see it), but it's printing CYMK. what printer settings do i have to change?

Comment: Hi user61871, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

You can't print RGB. The colour range and the way that colours are constructed are so different between screen and print, that any print will *always* be CMYK.

We have a great Q&A about the difference between the two colour spaces [right here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60/what-is-the-difference-between-cmyk-and-rgb-are-there-other-color-spaces-i-shou). Go and read up on your colour space theory right there!

Comment: "the way that colors are constructed" = RGB is constructive in that it is built using light; CMYK is destructive in that it filters light reflecting off of the surface. CMY are (more or less) the inverse of RGB incidentally, so the ink dots  are kind of like little color filters

Comment: I think he does not ment "print" but exporting that as perhaphs a pdf to be viewed online.